# In VS Code, what is the difference between a project and a workspace or folder?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I know the difference between a workwpace and an folder (and this question has already been answered).

But what is the difference between a project and a workspace? Or between a project and a folder?

Some people are using this term (project), but I don't see any explantion about it in the VS Code documentation.